# Performing Bash substring substitution and vim keeps showing syntax errors- bad syntax or false flag?

Tags: string, bash

Here are the contents of file "code.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash

x=Funtime/CandyBeer20171018.txt

a=${x:(-12):8} #start 12 characters from the end of string and select 8 characters
echo $a
```

When I open "code.sh" in vim, line 3 returns a syntax error in red, the portion of text that is red being ":(-12):8". I'm using vim on Xubuntu 14.04.

That being said, the code works as desired- when I run the script, it returns only the string "20171018".

1. Is my syntax incorrect or this a false flag?
2. If syntax is incorrect, can someone help me fix it or show me a different solution? Keep in mind it is important that I be able to cut using the end of the string as a reference point

I am ripping my hair out here, please help. I've played with cut, head and tail for hours and this is the closest I've been able to get to a solution using a negative index.

Comment: Your syntax is fine, if you're using a new enough shell to support it.

Comment: BTW, next time you want a sanity check on your syntax, consider using [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: So is this is common in vim? This is the first time I've gotten gotten a false flag in vim and I find this a bit unsettling

Comment: Yes, it's common in vim.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out. So is doing a "sanity check" as simple as cutting and pasting the above code into that website you referred me to?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Just be sure to include a proper "she-bang" line at the top, usually, `#!/bin/bash` . Good luck.

Comment: You can also install ShellCheck locally -- there's a vim extension to run it automatically, though I'd need to go look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Charles Duffy kindly let me know, vim is not at all the final authority when it comes to evaluating syntax errors. vim *can* flag good code as having a syntax error (which is great to know, I naively thought that vim could be trusted to properly detect syntax errors).

Charles Duffy also made me aware of an awesome program called shellcheck that runs sanity checks on bash/sh scripts.

So I merely installed shellcheck (on Xubuntu 14.04) with:

```
sudo apt-get install shellcheck
```

Then I ran the following code to do a sanity check on my script:

```
shellcheck code.sh
```

It returned no output (meaning that there were no syntax errors), indicating, like Charles Duffy said, that vim cannot be trusted to always give good syntax advice.

As an aside, I ran shellcheck on some of my scripts and the feedback it gives is simply amazing!! Showed me tons of amazing suggestions to improve my scripts, and helped me debug an error I couldn't pinpoint on one of my more tricky scripts. I cannot recommend shellcheck enough for people working with bash scripts!!

Thanks again Charles Duffy!!

Comment: If you install `vim-syntastic`, you can get shellcheck suggestions directly in vim